# Margin calculation with D3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, layout, d3.js, margin

I'm drawing couple of graphics on a webpage. Let's say I have 4 graphics (A-B-C-D). I would like to lay them out as follows:

```
A B
C D
```

But currently they appear like this:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I set the margin, width, and height for A as follows:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Any ideas on how to set these (or some other) properties for B, C and D so that they appear as intended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set them .style('display', 'inline-block') and set the width to less than 50% or put a `</br>` tag between them.